# Map with Dapper one table to a nested object

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a table which has the following columns:

| UserId | UserName | SortCode | AccountNumber |

And I have the following C# classes

```
    public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string SortCode { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I need to map the SortCode column to the Account.SortCode object. The same with the AccountNumber.

I was trying something like this

```
 const string query = @"SELECT UserId, UserName, SortCode AS [Account.SortCode], AccountNumber AS [Account.AccountNumber], FROM [dbo].[Users];";

 return db.Query<User>(query);
```

But is is not working.
Any help?.

Thanks!!

Comment: Dapper doesn't try to understand the relationships between objects.  You have to tell it how to relate them.  Look at the Dapper documentation about "Multi Mapping".

Answer (score 0):

Following @Amy's comment, this did the trick:

```
    const string query = @"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Users];";

    return db.Query<User, Account, User>(query, (user, account) => 
    {
       user.Account = account;
       return user;
    }, splitOn: "UserId");
```

Thanks!